# (bash) How to access chunks of command output as discrete array elements?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, concatenation

```
nmcli -t -f STATE,WIFI,WWAN
```

gives the output

```
connected:enabled:disabled
```

which I'd like to convert to something like

```
Networking: connected, Wifi: enabled, WWAN: disabled
```

The logical solution to me is to turn this into an array. Being quite new to bash scripting, I have read that arrays are just regular variables and the elements are separated by whitespace. Currently my code is

```
declare -a NMOUT=$(nmcli -t -f STATE,WIFI,WWAN nm | tr ":" "\n")
```

which seems to sort of work for a for loop, but not if i want to ask for a specific element, as in ${NMOUT[]}. Clearly I am missing out on some key concept here. How do I access specific elements in this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams provided a much better solution for creating the array. I will address the posted question.

Array's in bash are indexed by integers starting at 0.

```
"${NMOUT[0]}" # first element of the array
"${NMOUT[2]}" # third element of the array
"${NMOUT[@]}" # All array elements
"${NMOUT[*]}" # All array elements as a string
```

The following provides good information on using arrays in bash: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005

Comment: thanks for the link; looks useful! i ended up giving up after finding another command whose output was already formatted the way i needed, but this will be useful to know in the future.

Comment: @dn3s The best way to say "thanks" is by upvoting or accepting answers.

Comment: sorry about that. accepted, but can't upvote yet due to lack of rep.

Answer (score 2):

```
IFS=: read -a NMOUT < <(nmcli -t -f STATE,WIFI,WWAN)
```